# Give the Big-O estimates

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o

I'm supposed to determine the time complexity of this algorithm:

```
x:=1                       // (1) 
for i:=1 to n do           // (3n+1)
    for j:=1 to i do       // (3n)
        x:=max(x, i*j)     // 3*(3n+1)*(3n)
return x
```

I got O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), but that's not the right answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: and what is the expected answer ?

Comment: Why do you think you have made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity will be `O(n*(n+1)) ~ O(n*2)`. Because second loop till i every time it will run (1,2,3,4....) times.

Comment: `O(n*(n+1) / 2) = O(n*n/2 + n/2) = O(n**2 + n)/2 = O(n**2 + n) = O(n**2)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, the complexity will be O(n^2). Since there execute `X := max(X,i*j)` n(1+n)/2 times, we can get n^2/2 <= complexity <= n^2.